# Any future king is the oldest male child. The future king has two siblings what is the probability he has an older sister?

Tags: probability

So I have this probability question which I am having trouble solving and was wondering whether anyone could provide an explanation as to how to do it? Thanks.

Any future king is the oldest male child. The future king has two siblings what is the probability he has an older sister?

Comment: Well this might help.  He can have a older sister, a younger sister, or a younger brother.

Comment: What are all the possible sequences of three children that include a male child?  In how many of these sequences does a female child precede the first male?

Comment: May we assume that, for instance, the probability of male and female children is equal, and that all children are either male or female? May we assume that there's been no fratricide? May we assume that the sex of child $A$ does not depend in any way on the sex of his or her older siblings?

Answer (score 2):

(Making the assumptions that sex of each birth is independent and unbiased.)

There are $\bbox[lemonchiffon]{\phantom{2^3-1}}$ equally probable three-sibling families which contain a future king (male child).  Ie: that don't contain all female children.

There are $\bbox[lemonchiffon]{\phantom{2^2-1}}$ equally probable such families which contain a future king *and* his elder sister.

Fill in the blanks, divide and calculate.

Comment: Thank you or the responses. I get a sample space of 7. BBB BBG BGB BGG GBB GBG GGB (GGG) not used. Only GBB GBG and GGB fit the criteria. So I get 3/7 but the answer in my textbook is 1/2. Am I missing something?